# react bootstrap navbar toggle not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react bootstrap to make my navbar.
When the width of the window is small, the toggle button appears,
but after clicking the button, my nav-items just can't appear.
It seams that the navbar's height is fix.
How to fix this?

**This is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Payments from "./Payments";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavDropdown,
  MenuItem,
  Container,
  Card,
  Button
} from "react-bootstrap";

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
          <LinkContainer to={this.props.auth ? "/surveys" : "/"}>
            <Navbar.Brand>Emaily</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </Container>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
  return { auth };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

Comment: I fixed it. The reason is conflict between style sheets of materialize design and react-bootstrap.

Comment: Hey, how did you resolve the conflict?  I am having the same issue.  Using Material UI from some components but its causing the NavBar icon to not show.  Thanks.